# Mouse disconnects when I flick at high speed

Tags: usb, mouse, hardware-failure, wireshark, usbpcap

**Issue**

I use a zowie [EC2-A mouse](https://zowie.benq.com/en-ca/mouse/ec2-a.html) to play fps games.

I'm using a custom built PC running windows 10.

I've been noticing recently that when I flick the mouse quickly to the right or left that it will disconnect for about half a second. This is quite frustrating since I flick in high intensity moments and the mouse disconnecting is the last thing I want.

This issue happens about 90% of the time on a hard flick, so it seems quite consistent.

The reason I know that it is disconnecting is that it plays the windows 10 usb disconnect jingle followed by the reconnect one.

**What I tried**

*Physical*

I've tried the mouse out on a different laptop, flicking hard (to the same extent as on the desktop) doesn't cause a disconnect, so I feel as though the mouse is alright, but something weird is going on with my desktop.

Trying out different ports (back and front panel, usb3.0 , regular usb) all have the disconnection on flick on the desktop.

*Software*

I next downloaded USBPcap and Wireshark. After starting the USB packet monitor I unplugged all other devices and replicated the mouse flick disconnect issue. This is what the monitor shows during this flick and disconnect event:

```
No. Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Length  Info
8546    29.476304   host    2.1.1   USB 27  URB_INTERRUPT in
8547    29.478249   2.1.1   host    USB 33  URB_INTERRUPT in
8548    29.478290   host    2.1.1   USB 27  URB_INTERRUPT in
8549    29.480259   2.1.1   host    USB 33  URB_INTERRUPT in
8550    29.480304   host    2.1.1   USB 27  URB_INTERRUPT in
8551    29.482260   2.1.1   host    USB 33  URB_INTERRUPT in
8552    29.482304   host    2.1.1   USB 27  URB_INTERRUPT in
8553    29.484053   2.1.1   host    USB 27  URB_INTERRUPT in
8554    29.484057   2.1.1   host    USB 27  URB_INTERRUPT in
8555    29.488452   host    2.1.1   USB 27  URB_FUNCTION_ABORT_PIPE
8556    29.488469   2.1.1   host    USB 27  URB_FUNCTION_ABORT_PIPE
8557    29.794484   host    2.1.0   USB 36  GET DESCRIPTOR Request DEVICE
8558    29.798269   2.1.0   host    USB 46  GET DESCRIPTOR Response DEVICE
8559    29.798327   host    2.1.0   USB 36  GET DESCRIPTOR Request CONFIGURATION
8560    29.802248   2.1.0   host    USB 37  GET DESCRIPTOR Response CONFIGURATION
8561    29.802303   host    2.1.0   USB 36  GET DESCRIPTOR Request CONFIGURATION
8562    29.809248   2.1.0   host    USB 62  GET DESCRIPTOR Response CONFIGURATION
8563    29.809296   host    2.1.0   USB 36  SET CONFIGURATION Request
8564    29.814300   2.1.0   host    USB 28  SET CONFIGURATION Response
8565    29.814321   host    2.1.0   USBHID  36  SET_IDLE Request
8566    29.815243   2.1.0   host    USBHID  28  SET_IDLE Response
8567    29.815367   host    2.1.0   USBHID  36  GET DESCRIPTOR Request HID Report
8568    29.826255   2.1.0   host    USBHID  97  GET DESCRIPTOR Response HID Report
8569    29.828037   host    2.1.1   USB 27  URB_INTERRUPT in
8570    29.828069   host    2.1.1   USB 27  URB_INTERRUPT in
8571    29.886293   2.1.1   host    USB 33  URB_INTERRUPT in
8572    29.886347   host    2.1.1   USB 27  URB_INTERRUPT in
8573    29.888255   2.1.1   host    USB 33  URB_INTERRUPT in
8574    29.888263   host    2.1.1   USB 27  URB_INTERRUPT in
```

From what I understand, the average mouse movement request is a communication from 2.1.1 (the mouse) to host (my pc), clicking on one of these events shows:

[image: Successful event]

Where it looks like the message has gotten from the mouse to the computer successfully. After that it looks like a message is sent from the host back to 2.1.1 (maybe some type of confirmation):

[image: Maybe confirmation]

Interestingly if we look at the packets being sent right before the lines with `URB_FUNCTION_ABORT_PIPE`, there are two requests from 2.2.1 to host, with a cancelled status:

[image: Cancelled URB_FUNCTION_ABORT_PIPE]

Then the host successfully sends the `URB_FUNCTION_ABORT_PIPE`, but the mouse's response says it's an invalid parameter:

[image: URB_FUNCTION_ABORT_PIPE response]

Finally, right before the mouse starts functioning again, the host asks for the descriptor for the mouse, in which the mouse responds with:

[image: Descriptor response]

And the mouse continues normal operation.

At this point I still don't know what the issue is and I'm unable to flick my mouse without it disconnecting. Does anyone have any recommendations here?

Comment: I don't have any real basis to support this other than just a gut feeling, but I think it's possibly either a power supply problem or an electrical problem with the chassis itself.

Comment: Does this occur when running in safe mode?

Comment: I tried running in safe mode, and yes, I still get this issue, I also just tried with a different wired mouse, and it didn't occur.

Comment: Something I notice is that my mouse seems to be building up static as I can hear the little zaps when I lift my mouse off the pad. The more flicks I do across the pad the more intense the static is. I'm going to turn on my humidifier, and see if the problem persists

Comment: You might also want to try rubbing your mousepad with a dryer sheet and see if it still does that?

Comment: Is there any visible damage along the wiring?  Are you able to pinpoint exactly where the "zap" is occurring?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to pinpoint the zap, but I can feel build up on the feet of the mouse after sliding it across the mousepad.

Comment: I've also plugged it into the front panel again, and the disconnections have seemed to stop, so maybe the back panel can't handle the static electricity as well as the front one?

Comment: Perhaps, which is why I suggested wiping the mousepad down with a dryer sheet, as this should apply an anti-static effect on the surface.  For best results, you may want to dampen the dryer sheet prior to doing so, as it is actioned through a chemical agent.

Comment: I tried doing everything that was mentioned by @Arctiic but I wasn't able to get the mouse working, I finally ended up getting a new mouse which has completely fixed the issue. If you encounter the same issues that I had it is most likely a hardware issue and if you have the patience debug the hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem as you and I tried to fix it a lot using many methods using software like MouseTester and USB Analyze.

**MouseTester Results**:
[image: MouseTester Results]

That's why I turned to software like USB Analyzer And here I found your post

> URB_FUNCTION_ABORT_PIPE

The problem was not with the software. The problem was with the hardware. I changed the cable connecting the mouse and the computer, and the problem was completely solved. I hope this helps you.